Second call to "get" method of Supplier is empty
For the below code, if I make a second call to supplier with "get" method, the count is zero.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class FileOperations {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOperations fOps = new FileOperations();

        fOps.usingBufferedReader();

    }

    public void usingBufferedReader() {
        Path path = Path.of("app_log.log");
        
        /**
         * Only first operation with stream provide results.
         */
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);) {
            Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> reader.lines();
            
            streamSupplier.get().forEach(ln -> {
                System.out.println(ln);                 // Prints all lines properly
            });
            
            long count = streamSupplier.get().count();
            System.out.println("count = " + count);     // Outputs "0"
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
    }
}

I tried having count as first call to streamSupplier.get.
long count = streamSupplier.get().count();
System.out.println("count = " + count);     // Outputs "0"

At that time it properly printed the count as 528, but didn't printed the lines of the file.
I'm using Java 17

Calling lines() a second time will not reset reader back the start of the file. Hence count()=zero on the second call.

DuncG gave the correct answer in his comment, but let me go a bit deeper.
reader.lines() returns a new stream over the lines of the reader. Like any stream it doesn't do anything until a terminal operation is called. When you call forEach the stream will start reading lines, either using readLine() in the background or doing something similar. Either way it will read all content from the reader. When the stream is done the reader's content has been consumed; calling reader.read() will return -1.
When you call the supplier again, reader.lines() returns a new stream. But like DuncG said, the backing reader hasn't been reset, all of its content still has been consumed, and the result is that no lines are available - the stream is empty.

The whole idea of Supplier is to keep one stream operation not to interfere with other stream operation right? As it had returned new Stream both in case of first call and second call, reder.read() has only operated on one of the copy of the Stream right?
Why does the second fresh copy should consider where the previous reader is pointing?
Both of them are separate copies.

@learner You don't have a copy of the BufferedReader, only a copy of the Stream. If you do create a copy of the BufferedReader using a Supplier<BufferedReader> supplier = () -> Files.newBufferedReader(path);, it should work as expected. Remember to close the previous reader before calling supplier.get().

Apart from the IOException that needs to be handled, @Sweeper is right. You could also use () -> Files.line(path) as Supplier<Stream<String>>, but then too you need to a) handle the IOException, and b) close the stream (the Stream<String> wraps something that needs to be closed, and it does so when the stream is closed).
